# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND

Tags: php, syntax-error

I get this error in my PHP code:

```
Parse error:syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND in /home/a1825511/public_html/register.php on line 23
```

This is my code:

```
if (strlet($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, ".")) {
```

What am I doing wrong? By the way that end bracket does connect later in my code, so all good there.

Comment: What is `strlet()`? Should that be `strlen()`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes thank you for noticing that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have lost one after `if`

```
if ((strlet($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, ".")))
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error that says I have an unexpected {... @iatboy

Comment: @AgentMcBride, yes , I forgot a `{` at the last

Answer (score 1):

Count your parenthesis. You have at least one too many.

```
if (strlen($getemail) >= 7 && strstr($getemail, "@") && strstr($getemail, ".")) {
```

Comment: Thank you. Very simple mistake, Im still learning! @JohnConde